# Mercurial: devs work on separate folders, why do they have to merge all the time

Tags: mercurial

I have four devs working in four separate source folders in a mercurial repo. Why do they have to merge all the time and pollute the repo with merge changesets? It annoys them and it annoys me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the changes *really don't conflict*, you can use the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) in lieu of merging.

First, put this in your `.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```

Now, instead of merging, just do `hg rebase`.  It will "detach" your local changesets and move them to be descendants of the public tip.  You can also pass various arguments to modify what gets rebased.

Again, this is **not a good idea** if your developers are going to encounter physical merge conflicts, or logical conflicts (e.g. Alice changed a feature in file A at the same time as Bob altered related functionality in file B).  In those cases, you should probably use a real merge in order to properly represent the relevant history.  `hg rebase` can be easily aborted if physical conflicts are encountered, but it's a good idea to check for logical conflicts by hand, since the extension cannot detect those automatically.

Comment: Interesting. I'm interested to see how that integrates in eclipse. But it's not straight forward, because they can make a mistake. I don't want the repo to depend on them being careful

Comment: Also in eclipse when you rebase, you still have to merge.

Comment: @mist: That doesn't make any sense to me.  After a properly-done rebase, there is only one line of development.  It should not even be *possible* to do a merge at that point.  As for carefulness, the repo *does* depend on them being careful whether you like it or not.  If they're careless, the resulting code will be buggy and wrong.

Comment: I will send you a screenshot. Eclipse's plugin calls it change tip or smth

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2rmoxur.jpg, I guess this is the "hg rebase" in eclipse's plugin. After it. I most definitely have to merge.

Comment: Here's an example with rebase (they do merge at the end): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672351/hg-how-to-do-a-rebase-like-gits-rebase

Comment: @mist: The accepted answer to that question isn't doing a rebase, and the questioner is not doing a merge.  You do one or the other, not both.  Also, I don't see how "replace current with selected" is at all the same thing as "rebase."

Comment: What is "replace current with selected" then?

Comment: @mist: It's not standard Mercurial terminology.  You'll have to consult the Eclipse documentation.

Comment: Also, what if the received updates clash with my changes I want to rebase? How will the rebase know how to "merge"? Will there be an error?

Comment: @mist: Rebasing uses the same logic as merging.  While it is possible to clean up after conflicts, it's usually better to abort the rebase (with `hg rebase --abort`) and then do a real merge in that case.

Comment: so rebase will work fine (and is supposed to be used only ) if there are no conflicts?

Comment: @mist: Yes, rebasing is designed primarily for the "no conflicts" use case.  It can be used if there are conflicts, but this may make your commit history harder to understand, which is probably not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your development team are committing little and often; **this is just what you want** so you don't want to change that habit for the sake of a clean line of commits.

@Kevin has described using the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) and I agree that can work fine. However, you'll also see all the work sequence of each developer squished together in a single line of commits. If you're working on a stable code base and just submitting quick single-commit fixes then that may be fine - if you have ongoing lines of development then you might not won't want to lose the continuity of a developer's commits.

Another option is to split your repository into smaller self-contained repositories.

If your developers are always working in 4 separate folders, perhaps the contents of these folders can be modularised and stored as separate Mercurial repositories. You could then have a separate master repository that brought all these smaller repositories together within the [sub-repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, very rarely, they touch each other's code. Also the code is interconnected, so I don't want it to be in separate repositories.

Comment: You can still interconnect the code using a master repository. It does sound like the 99% case suits modular repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is *distributed*, it means that if you have a central repository, every developer *also* has a private repository on his/her workstation, and also a working copy of course.

So now let's suppose that they make a change and commit it, i.e., to their private repository. When they want to *hg push* two things can happen:

- either they are the first one to push a new changeset on the central server, then no merge will be required, or
- either somebody else, starting from the same version, has committed and pushed **before** them. We can see that there is a fork here: from the same starting point Mercurial has two different directions, thus a merge is required, even if there is no conflict, because we do not want four different divergent contexts on the central server (which by the way is possible with Mercurial, they are called *heads* and you can force the push without merge, but you still have the divergence, no magic, and this is probably not what you want because you want to be able to checkout the sum of all the contributions..).

Now how to avoid performing merges is quite simple: you need to tell your developers to **integrate others changes before committing** their own changes:

```
$ hg pull
$ hg update
$ hg commit -m"..."
$ hg push
```

When the commit is made against the latest central version, no merge should be required.
If they where working on the same code, after pull and update some running of tests would be required as well to ensure that what was working in isolation still works when other developers work have been integrated. Taking others contributions frequently and pushing our own changes also frequently is called continuous integration and ensures that integration issues are discovered quickly.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. So if they don't have their work committed, there is no merge changeset created. Makes sense. Unfortunately until they do all that, someone commits something. They do very small changes. So I have to figure a way to automate all that in eclipse.

Comment: @mist or they could try to make it a habit of always pulling the central repo before commiting.. (which is a good habit!). :)

Comment: Hm, while in this particular case (developers working in separate directories), this strategy may work, I don't agree in general on 'pulling before committing'. If you have merge conflicts and you mess them up, there's no way back if you haven't committed. As such, I prefer committing first (and using 'pull --rebase' with evolve to safely rebase).

Comment: pulling before committing would be very limiting. it would be  race to make your commits before someone else happens to push code. rebase is more appropriate if you want to keep a linear set & avoid merges.