# Mercurial resolve two heads conflict

Tags: merge, mercurial, repository, push

I accidentally committed changes before pulling the latest version from the repository, and know I am stuck with this:

```
changeset:   79:8092df3d1614
tag:         tip
user:        Daniel
date:        Thu Jun 29 16:55:35 2017 +0100
summary:     removed missing files

changeset:   76:8ce070e31679
parent:      74:724b36f18d94
user:        Daniel 
date:        Thu Jun 29 02:06:37 2017 +0100
summary:     revision
```

When I push I get abort:

```
push creates new remote head 8092df3d1614
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In general you *should* combine your changes with the other changes, either by merging or by rebasing.  See [Hg: How to do a rebase like git's rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672351/1256452), which has several examples.

It is possible to push the extra head anyway, using the force flag.  The reason *not* to do this is that others will no longer know which head is "headier": which one should *they* use?  The reason *to* do this is that you may not know how to, or want to, merge or rebase your changes; you and your colleagues may wish to fork the development within a single branch (perhaps using bookmarks, which will help you and your colleages track which head *is* headier, for which purpose).

The final course of action to take is up to you (and your colleagues).